# WinAPI. Изменить размер HDC

Tags: winapi

Программа открывает изображения так:

```
global::HDCA = GetDC(global::hwnd);
    global::HDCB = CreateCompatibleDC(global::HDCA);
    global::HBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, global::path, IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0, LR_CREATEDIBSECTION | LR_LOADFROMFILE);
    GetObject(global::HBitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), &global::Bitmap);
    global::HGDIOBj = SelectObject(global::HDCB, global::HBitmap);
```

Когда изображения большие - легко их уменьшать и отображать алгоритмически.
Но когда изображения маленькие  увеличить - отображается только часть в рамках начального размера, все остальное отсекается. Путем проб, было выяснено, что вся проблема в строке:

```
global::HBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, global::path, IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0, LR_CREATEDIBSECTION | LR_LOADFROMFILE);
```

Которая фиксирует размер изображения как будто навсегда. И увеличить его с 320 на 640 просто подставив:

```
Bitmap.bmWidth = 640;
```

Не выходит. Соответственно все нарисованные пиксели в SetPixel() за рамкой первоначального размера уже не отображаются.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что нужно сделать чтоб изображение увеличилось вместе с  HDC и всем остальным?

Answer (score 2):

Изменить размер контекста устройства невозможно, потому что он представляет само устройство. У вас же монитор не увеличится если вы какую-нибудь переменную поменяете? Вот и его контекст тоже не увеличится.

Аналогично загруженное изображение не изменит размер просто из-за изменения `bmWidth`. Для изменения размера изображения его надо явным образом преобразовать.

Конкретно в вашем случае надо использовать функцию WinAPI [StretchDIBits](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-stretchdibits), которая копирует изображение целиком или частью в указанную область контекста устройства, с произвольным изменением размера.